# How to use Hibernate Validator with Primefaces Client Site Validation (CSV)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hibernate-validator

I followed Primefaces 5.1 guide and I'm able to make Client Site Validation (CSV) working with Bean Validation (JSR 349). I have

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.TRANSFORM_METADATA</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

With this set up, standard `@Size` or `@Pattern` are working without a roundtrip to server. However annotations like `@Email` from Hibernate Validator are not working at all. Primefaces in their *User Guide* describes **3rd Party Annotations** as

> When using 3rd party constraints like Hibernate Validator specific annotations, use
>   BeanValidationMetadataMapper to define a ClientValidationConstraint for them.

```
BeanValidationMetadataMapper.registerConstraintMapping(Class<? extends Annotation>
constraint, ClientValidationConstraint clientValidationConstraint);

BeanValidationMetadataMapper.removeConstraintMapping(Class<? extends Annotation>
constraint);
```

This sounds really enigmatic to me. Does anyone knows how the set up should look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For @NotBlank for example:

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.util;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.primefaces.validate.bean.BeanValidationMetadataMapper;

import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.validation.NotBlankClientValidationConstraint;

@WebListener
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false");

    BeanValidationMetadataMapper.registerConstraintMapping(NotBlank.class, 
            new NotBlankClientValidationConstraint());
}

}
```

And the ClientValidationConstraint itself:

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.validation;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.metadata.ConstraintDescriptor;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.primefaces.validate.bean.ClientValidationConstraint;

public class NotBlankClientValidationConstraint implements  ClientValidationConstraint {

public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}";

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getMetadata(ConstraintDescriptor constraintDescriptor) {
    Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map attrs = constraintDescriptor.getAttributes();

    Object message = attrs.get("message");

    if (!message.equals(MESSAGE_ID)) {
        metadata.put("data-msg-notblank", message);
    }

    return metadata;
}

@Override
public String getValidatorId() {
    return NotBlank.class.getSimpleName();
}

}
```

Assuming that code works, because it was "borrowed" from here:

[Listener](https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/TemaBootstrap/src/main/java/com/algaworks/pedidovenda/util/AppContextListener.java)

[ClientValidationConstraint](https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/TemaBootstrap/src/main/java/com/algaworks/pedidovenda/validation/NotBlankClientValidationConstraint.java)

And don't forget about:

```
PrimeFaces.validator.NotBlank = {

MESSAGE_ID : 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message',

validate : function(element, value) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || value.trim() === '') {
        var msg = element.data('msg-notblank');
        var label = element.data('p-label');
        var context = PrimeFaces.util.ValidationContext;
        var msgObj;

        if (!msg) {
            msgObj = context.getMessage(this.MESSAGE_ID, label);
        } else {
            var msgObj = {
                summary : msg,
                detail : msg
            }
        }

        throw msgObj;
    }
}

};
```